# GWT DataGrid -- CSS Border Won't Take Effect

Tags: css, gwt, border

I'm trying to add a border around my DataGrid GWT element.  I've had limited success overriding the default CSS classes defined in the [official GWT DataGrid CSS file](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.css?r=10228). I can successfully override the ".dataGridEvenRow" and ".dataGridOddRow" with border-style and border-top attributes and the border becomes visible around those rows, but when I try overriding the ".dataGridWidget" and add border CSS attributes as displayed in the code below no border appears.

```
.dataGridWidget
{
   border-style:ridge;
   border-width:5px;
   border-color: blue;
}
```

What can one do to get a blue border around appearing around a DataGrid?

Comment: From the limited code you have provided, it seems like it should work. However, it is very difficult for the community to debug without the full context. Is it possible for you to post a jsfiddle or sample page?

Comment: What do you mean by "overriding"? Do you add the same style to your external CSS file, or you construct the DataGrid with your own styles?

Comment: Add the same style to an external CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours trying to get the styling to work directly on the DataGrid, I decided to just wrap the DataGrid using a SimplePanel and add my border directly to that.  It looks exactly like a border around the DataGrid itself, and since the other DataGrid classes seem to override without any problems (like dataGridEvenRow and dataGridOddRow), it's a seamless band-aid to the issue.